# Derivation of Bohr model equations (1) in his original paper

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, atomic-physics

My question is rather straightforward. In his original paper ("On the Constitution of Atoms and Molecules") Bohr provides equations (1) for the frequency and major axis orbit:

\begin{align}
\omega &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} \frac{W^{3/2}}{eE\sqrt{m}}\\
2a &= \frac{eE}{W}
\end{align}
where $W$ is the energy of the electron, $e$ its charge and $E$ the charge of the nucleus.

How exactly did he derive these equations? I have some troubles doing that. Many thanks.

Radek

Comment: What's a? Bohr used classical mechanics for the most part of his model (the force between the electron and the nucleus is the well known Coulomb law that only depends on the separation between them,  $-\frac{Ze^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$ (with $Z$ the nuclear charge).  The big step was boldly asserting that the angular momentum of the electron, $m v r$ was quantised, namely $m v r = n \hbar$.

Comment: $2a$ is major axis of the elliptical orbit. See the article: http://web.ihep.su/dbserv/compas/src/bohr13/eng.pdf. For circular motion it seems to be simple. Have troubles with elliptical case.

Comment: OK, agree the elliptical case is more complicated than the circular case. Surprised that the quantisation condition seems to have been introduced by asserting $W=\tau h\frac{\omega}{2}$, I'd always thought that it was via angular momentum (see Eqn (2))

Comment: The angular momentum quantization was a *result*. I've never understood why textbooks give the impression that it was a starting point. The starting point was requiring the energies to yield Rydberg like transitions---force the theory to give the data and see if the results make any sense.

Comment: @Radek May be you'll have a little help in : " Collected Works, Vol. 02 - Work on Atomic Physics (1912-1917) [Bohr]". Kepler 3rd Law is definitely one of the laws used by Bohr. In theses links : http://i.imgur.com/jkPETWw.jpg, http://i.imgur.com/Rawogff.jpg, http://i.imgur.com/8EFxCCc.jpg, http://i.imgur.com/Ucez6Bu.jpg  you'll find 4 pages. 2 of them are notes handwritten by Bohr.